# How to manually trigger Laravel model event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-events

When no data is changed then laravel checks for isDirty and never executed the update query and hence model updated event is not fired. How can we manually trigger an event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To manually trigger an event

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->fill($data);
$user->save();

event('eloquent.updated: App\User', $user);
```

Comment: That would trigger the observer twice.

Comment: Can I ask, which version of laravel is this. any response will be appreciated.

Comment: @Jovylle I'm not sure if it helps, but I can confirm it works on Laravel 8.83.9