# Event of model not fire when use in Query Scopes

Tags: laravel, events, model, laravel-9

I am using laravel 9, PHP 8.1.

I noticed the following problem:

```
// App\Model\Store

class Store extends Model
{
    ....

    public function scopeUpdateStore($query, $id) {
        Store::find($id)->update(['name' => 'foo']);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then if I use :

```
Store::updateStore($id)->first();
```

Event `updating` and `updated` will not fire.

But when I use in controller:

```
// StoreController

Store::find($id)->update(['name'])
```

Event `updating` and `updated` will fire.

My problem is that it is not clear why there is this difference, and is there a way to make the event fireable in the `Query Scope`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're using [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes) to perform database updates. *Local scopes allow you to define common sets of **query constraints** that you may easily re-use throughout your application.*

Comment: It is also most likely because the `name` column value for that updated Model was already set to `'foo'` prior. Hence, no actual changes were made. Effectively, no model events would be fired in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually trigger Laravel model event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597719/how-to-manually-trigger-laravel-model-event)

Comment: First, you need to know we're not doing any CURD inside the model. As you said ***But when I use in controller Event updating and updated will fire.*** Cz that's how it meant to work

Comment: that is not what scopes are for, you just want to define a regular method to call ...

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa My intention when using update at query scope will be for updating more information from related tables like images or categories of store for example.
I think it's like if I extend the `update` method, instead of updating the information in one table, I will update the related tables.